# MongoDB: Upgrade 2.4.10 to 2.6

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb standalone instance in my ubuntu. According to [official docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/#upgrade-mongodb-processes) I replace mongod binary then I restarted mongodb using `sudo service mongodb restart` command, and restarted mongod binary also. Then when I check version using `mongo --version`. It's still 2.4.10. But when I check mongod version it's 2.6.1. Is it okay? I installed mongodb in my local machine using [this guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb). If it correct then I will upgrade my production server.

Comment: It's clear that my answer is irrelevant here. If you unaccept it I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's okay. The 2.6.1 version is a small update with bugfixes after version 2.6. But it's still the same major version.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm upgraded it from 2.4.10 is it fine also?

Comment: @Zeck If that's the version you have, yes. it was the previous public release version.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have upgraded your `mongod` server to 2.6.1 but still have an older version of the `mongo` shell in your path.

Technically that isn't a major issue for most usage as the older 2.4 shell can still connect and run common commands.

However, there are 2.6-specific shell helpers & features you'll be missing out on such as [Bulk() operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) and [user management commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/#user-management-commands) with user-defined roles.

If you have an open `mongo` shell, you can check the versions of both the `mongo` client and the `mongod` server you are connected to.

Ideally the major versions should match, eg:

```
> version() // Version of the `mongo` shell
2.6.1

> db.version() // Version of the `mongod` server this shell has connected to
2.6.1
```

The upgrade guide you have followed is assuming you are *not* using the packaged versions of MongoDB -- the guidance here could definitely be improved.

A better (and typical) approach for Ubuntu is to install MongoDB using the standard packages: [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). This would allow you to get software updates via the normal `apt-get` update process.